# array subscript is not an integer iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have this json

```
{"success":true,"content":{"Estados":[{"NombreEstado: ":"Distrito Federal","ExtensionGeografica: ":"16 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Aguascalientes","ExtensionGeografica: ":"14 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Baja California","ExtensionGeografica: ":"15 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Baja California Sur","ExtensionGeografica: ":"19 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Campeche","ExtensionGeografica: ":"8 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Coahuila de Zaragoza","ExtensionGeografica: ":"20 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Colima","ExtensionGeografica: ":"6 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Chiapas","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Chihuahua","ExtensionGeografica: ":"9 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Durango","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Guanajuato","ExtensionGeografica: ":"10 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Guerrero","ExtensionGeografica: ":"8 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Hidalgo","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Jalisco","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"M\u00e9xico","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Michoac\u00e1n de Ocampo","ExtensionGeografica: ":"20 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Morelos","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Nayarit","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Nuevo Le\u00f3n","ExtensionGeografica: ":"11 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Oaxaca","ExtensionGeografica: ":"6 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Puebla","ExtensionGeografica: ":"6 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Quer\u00e9taro","ExtensionGeografica: ":"10 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Quintana Roo","ExtensionGeografica: ":"12 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"San Luis Potos\u00ed","ExtensionGeografica: ":"16 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Sinaloa","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Sonora","ExtensionGeografica: ":"6 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Tabasco","ExtensionGeografica: ":"7 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Tamaulipas","ExtensionGeografica: ":"10 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Tlaxcala","ExtensionGeografica: ":"8 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Veracruz de Ignacio de la Llave","ExtensionGeografica: ":"31 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Yucat\u00e1n","ExtensionGeografica: ":"8 km"},{"NombreEstado: ":"Zacatecas","ExtensionGeografica: ":"9 km"}]},"generated":"2016-03-03"}
```

this is my class, i don´t know if i wrong on the parsing or what

```
NSDictionary * content = self.dictionary[@"content"];
                NSDictionary * states = content [@"Estados"];
                for (NSDictionary * dic in states ) {
                    [self.extension addObject:dict [@"ExtensionGeografica"]];
                    [self.extension addObject:dict [@"NombreEstado"]];
                }

                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
     }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.states count];
}
```

Edit 1

i Fix the first problem this how it look, the problem with array i think is works,

```
NSDictionary * content = self.dictionary[@"content"];
            NSMutableArray * states = content [@"Estados"];
            for (NSDictionary* dic in states ) {
                [self.extension addObject:dic [@"ExtensionGeografica"]];
                [self.extension addObject:dic [@"NombreEstado"]];
            }

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
```

now it does´t show information in my Cell

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [self.dic count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.stateName.text = [self.states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Julio, on what line is the error triggered?

Comment: `content[@"Estados"]` returns an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: [self.extension addObject:dict [@"ExtensionGeografica"]];

Comment: @rmaddy
So i need to change my NSDictionary states for a NSArray?

Comment: You declare your dictionary as `dic` but refer to it as `dict` in the loop

Comment: @dan
i fix that yet, thanks

Comment: `states` should be `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: You really need to work on your consistency. Your code for iterating the states populates an array named `self.extension`. Your `numberOfRowsInSection` is based on `self.dic`. And your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is based off of `self.states`. All three should be the same.

Comment: @rmaddy
so i need to use self.extension for everything you say?

Comment: That's up to you but your table view data source methods should be based on the same data you are populating. You certainly shouldn't be using 3 different arrays.

Comment: @rmaddy
thats right? 
 NSDictionary * content = self.dictionary[@"content"];
                NSArray * states = content [@"Estados"];
                for (NSDictionary* dic in states ) {
                    [self.states addObject:dic [@"ExtensionGeografica"]];
                    [self.states addObject:dic [@"NombreEstado"]];
                }
                
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
     }];
}

Comment: @JulioAlcocer maybe you can put your comment on your question page so it can easily be understood and not drill down on the comment section to find out the initialisation part